# Error when compiling Walrus Operator with Cython

Tags: python-3.x, cython

```
      conda version : 4.10.3
conda-build version : 3.21.5
     python version : 3.8.12.final.0
         user-agent : conda/4.10.3 requests/2.26.0 CPython/3.8.12 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.19042
```

cython                    0.29.24          py38hd77b12b_0    defaults

Recently I found that Walrus Operator was very useful for simplifing code. So I used it in some occassions. But when trying to build pyd file, it failed as below.

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
    def run_sth():
        path_list = list(Path().rglob('run.exe'))
        if path_list:
            try:
                process = run(pathlist[0], timeout=240)
                if (ret := process.returncode) == 0:
                       ^
------------------------------------------------------------

oflt.py:229:24: Expected ')', found ':'
```

Is there anything to solve this problem? Many thanks.

Comment: There is an open issue for this feature: https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/2636

Comment: If your version of numba doesn't implement it, don't use it.  People programmed python and numpy for years without it.

Comment: Apparently, the walrus operator was recently added to Cython: https://github.com/cython/cython/pull/3691

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of Cython (3.0.0a11) works with the walrus operator, but as of 9-9-2022 it is not the latest stable release on PyPi. To get it run "pip install Cython==3.0.0a11". This version worked for me.